# Use tryCatch skip to next value of loop upon error?

Tags: r, error-handling, exception, try-catch

I've read a few other SO questions about `tryCatch` and cuzzins, as well as the documentation:

- [Exception handling in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622777/exception-handling-in-r)
- [catching an error and then branching logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158780/r-catching-an-error-and-then-branching-logic)
- [How can I check whether a function call results in a warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903157/how-can-i-check-whether-a-function-call-results-in-a-warning)
- [Problems with Plots in Loop](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/problems-with-plots-in-loop-corrected-Email-td3597451.html)

but I still don't understand.

I'm running a loop and want to skip to `next` if any of a few kinds of errors occur:

```
for (i in 1:39487) {

  # EXCEPTION HANDLING
  this.could.go.wrong <- tryCatch(
                           attemptsomething(),
                           error=function(e) next
                         )
  so.could.this <- tryCatch(
                     doesthisfail(),
                     error=function(e) next
                   )

  catch.all.errors <- function() { this.could.go.wrong; so.could.this; }
  catch.all.errors;


  #REAL WORK
  useful(i); fun(i); good(i);

  }  #end for
```

*(by the way, there is no documentation for `next` that I can find)*

When I run this, `R` honks:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
```

What basic point am I missing here? The `tryCatch`'s are clearly within the `for` loop, so why doesn't `R` know that?

Answer (score 104):

The key to using `tryCatch` is realising that it returns an object.  If there was an error inside the `tryCatch` then this object will inherit from class `error`.  You can test for class inheritance with the function `inherit`.

```
x <- tryCatch(stop("Error"), error = function(e) e)
class(x)
"simpleError" "error"       "condition"
```

**Edit:**

What is the meaning of the argument `error = function(e) e`? This baffled me, and I don't think it's well explained in the documentation.  What happens is that this argument catches any error messages that originate in the expression that you are `tryCatch`ing.  If an error is caught, it gets returned as the value of `tryCatch`.  In the help documentation this is described as a `calling handler`.  The argument `e` inside `error=function(e)` is the error message originating in your code.

---

I come from the old school of procedural programming where using `next` was a bad thing.  So I would rewrite your code something like this. (Note that I removed the `next` statement inside the `tryCatch`.):

```
for (i in 1:39487) {
  #ERROR HANDLING
  possibleError <- tryCatch(
      thing(),
      error=function(e) e
  )

  if(!inherits(possibleError, "error")){
    #REAL WORK
    useful(i); fun(i); good(i);
  }

}  #end for
```

---

The function `next` is documented inside `?`for`.

If you want to use that instead of having your main working routine inside an `if`, your code should look something like this:

```
for (i in 1:39487) {
  #ERROR HANDLING
  possibleError <- tryCatch(
      thing(),
      error=function(e) e
  )

  if(inherits(possibleError, "error")) next

  #REAL WORK
  useful(i); fun(i); good(i);

}  #end for
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I originally had avoided `next` like you recommend, but as I thought of more and more errors that could possibly be caught, the code became a tangle of parentheses: as bad or worse than "programming" a series of conditionals inside an Excel cell.

Comment: When I run `?for` the next line is a `+`. (requesting more input)

Comment: @Andrie, what is the point of writing `error=function(e)` if the function is empty? Is that supposed to be shorthand for something else?

Comment: My mistake.  It should be `error=function(e) e`.  This returns the error message.  I have also added an explanation of this mechanism in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Andrie, that makes a little more sense. I will do some more reading about `calling handler`s.

Comment: I'm curious why you prefer to avoid 'next' - whether old school or new school, that's typically considered good practice IME.  Very very different from the "goto considered harmful" stuff, which is indeed quite harmful.  But loop control operators can greatly simplify code and eliminate sentinel variables, which have a tendency to have nasty edge cases.  And as @LaoTzu points out, you can save a lot of parens & braces.

Comment: @KenWilliams You are indeed correct that it is my personal hangover from "GOTO is bad". I'm gradually getting rid of this notion...

Comment: @Andrie Thanks for this. TryCatch is R works very differently than what we're taught in most programming languages.

Answer (score 97):

I found other answers very confusing. Here is an extremely simple implementation for anyone who wants to simply skip to the next loop iteration in the event of an error

```
for (i in 1:10) {

  skip_to_next <- FALSE

  # Note that print(b) fails since b doesn't exist

  tryCatch(print(b), error = function(e) { skip_to_next <<- TRUE})

  if(skip_to_next) { next }     
}
```

Comment: finally! so many convoluted explanations. but here you have simplified the whole process and in so doing, did a great service to the community. This should be the most upvoted answer!

Comment: For those who are confused by the `<<-`, that is not a typo. `<<-` is the superassignment operator. It does the assignment in the enclosing environment. That is, in this case, the `skip_to_next` from the for loop is being assigned a value from within `tryCatch()`. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628621/how-do-you-use-scoping-assignment-in-r).

Comment: Your answer is also a bit confusing, because you call `next` at the end of the loop, which is quite unnecessary in your case :-) Also, no need to `<<-`, since you can return value from the error handler and it will become the return value of `tryCatch`.

Comment: This answer is accurate, concise, and appreciated.

Comment: @stevec, I'm trying to get this to work for a for loop I'm running on a custom function. Something I'm still not getting: what part of your example should the "meat" of my loop go in?

Comment: @Abe the code that could error should go in place of `print(b)`. If you have multiple lines, place it all between curly brackets.

Comment: @stevec when calling `next`, should I put something inside the brackets or literally just `next`? For some reason, my code is still generating output and not breaking the loop when encountering an error, which is kind of confusing for me. It is also nested in multiple loops, so maybe I also have to specify that it should skip all loops when finding an error?

Comment: @Raksha literally just `next`

Comment: @stevec thanks! Do you have an idea why the code still generates output when finding an error? Should I write this `if(skip_to_next) { next }` again before the end of the outer loops?

Answer (score 7):

```
for (i in -3:3) {
  #ERROR HANDLING
  possibleError <- tryCatch({
    print(paste("Start Loop ", i ,sep=""))
    if(i==0){
      stop()
    }
  }
    ,
    error=function(e) {
      e
      print(paste("Oops! --> Error in Loop ",i,sep = ""))
    }
  )
  
  if(inherits(possibleError, "error")) next

  print(paste("  End Loop ",i,sep = ""))
  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One thing I was missing, which [breaking out of for loop when running a function inside a for loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513142/breaking-out-of-for-loop-when-running-a-function-inside-a-for-loop-in-r) makes clear, is this:

- `next` doesn't work inside a function.
- You need to send some signal or flag (e.g., `Voldemort = TRUE`) from inside your function (in my case `tryCatch`) to the outside.
- (this is like modifying a global, public variable inside a local, private function)
- Then outside the function, you check to see if the flag was waved (does `Voldemort == TRUE`). If so you call `break` or `next` outside the function.

Comment: in fact it is possible, not an elegant way but still: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2513647/2490497

Answer (score 5):

The only really detailed explanation I have seen can be found here: http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912

Here is a code clip from that blog post showing how tryCatch works

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
# tryCatch.r -- experiments with tryCatch

# Get any arguments
arguments <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
a <- arguments[1]

# Define a division function that can issue warnings and errors
myDivide <- function(d, a) {
  if (a == 'warning') {
    return_value <- 'myDivide warning result'
    warning("myDivide warning message")
  } else if (a == 'error') {
    return_value <- 'myDivide error result'
    stop("myDivide error message")
  } else {
    return_value = d / as.numeric(a)
  }
  return(return_value)
}

# Evalute the desired series of expressions inside of tryCatch
result <- tryCatch({

  b <- 2
  c <- b^2
  d <- c+2
  if (a == 'suppress-warnings') {
    e <- suppressWarnings(myDivide(d,a))
  } else {
    e <- myDivide(d,a) # 6/a
  }
  f <- e + 100

}, warning = function(war) {

  # warning handler picks up where error was generated
  print(paste("MY_WARNING:  ",war))
  b <- "changing 'b' inside the warning handler has no effect"
  e <- myDivide(d,0.1) # =60
  f <- e + 100
  return(f)

}, error = function(err) {

  # warning handler picks up where error was generated
  print(paste("MY_ERROR:  ",err))
  b <- "changing 'b' inside the error handler has no effect"
  e <- myDivide(d,0.01) # =600
  f <- e + 100
  return(f)

}, finally = {

  print(paste("a =",a))
  print(paste("b =",b))
  print(paste("c =",c))
  print(paste("d =",d))
  # NOTE:  Finally is evaluated in the context of of the inital
  # NOTE:  tryCatch block and 'e' will not exist if a warning
  # NOTE:  or error occurred.
  #print(paste("e =",e))

}) # END tryCatch

print(paste("result =",result))
```