# How to use trycatch to skip errors and move on to next in the list

Tags: r, text-mining

I want to parse rtf files from a folder in the rtf files that resulted in errors during the `lapply` step.

I am new to using `trycatch`, so how can I incorporate it in my code(the `lapply` step) to ignore the errors and continue with the parsing of the next rtf file?

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```r
yourFunction <- function(x) {
  rtf <- read_rtf(x, verbose = FALSE, row_start = "*| ", row_end = "",
                  cell_end = " | ", ignore_tables = FALSE, check_file = TRUE)

  text <- unlist(strsplit(rtf, "\\."))

  toMatch <- c("bitcoin", "fund")
  matches <- unique(grep(paste(toMatch,collapse="|"), 
                         text, value=TRUE))
  matches <- data.frame(matches)
}

results = lapply(files, function(x){
  tryCatch(yourFunction(x), 
           error = function(e)print(paste(x, 'did not want')), 
           finally = 0)})
```

Comment: It shows the error ‘’’Error in value [[3L]](cond) : attempt to apply non-function’’’

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot the `function(e)`-part. Should work now.

Comment: Since the `tryCatch`-help-page is a bit useless, you could have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8094059/9524065), which explains it better then I could ever do myself.

Answer (score 0):

What's about this ?

```
foo <- function(x) tryCatch(yourFunction(x), error = function(e) e)
lapply(files, foo)
```