# How to skip a holiday (which generates an error) in a loop?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I wrote code that scraps every day of the year and saves it in a separate .xlms file for each day.

```
start <- as.Date("25-01-19",format="%d-%m-%y")
end   <- as.Date("17-12-19",format="%d-%m-%y")

theDate <- start

while (theDate <= end)
{
  url <- (paste0("http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/produtos-e-servicos/emprestimo-de-ativos/renda-variavel/emprestimos-registrados/renda-variavel-8AE490CA64CD50310164D1EFD6412F1C.htm?data=",format(theDate,"%d/%m/%y"),"&f=0"))

  site <- read_html(url)

  Info_Ajuste_HTML <- html_nodes(site,'table')

  Info_ajuste <- html_text(Info_Ajuste_HTML)

  head(Info_ajuste,20)

  t <- head(Info_Ajuste_HTML)

  lista_tabela <- site %>%
      html_nodes("table") %>%
      html_table(fill = TRUE) 

  str(lista_tabela)

      head(lista_tabela[[1]], 10)

       if (t =="character(0)") {
         theDate <- theDate + 1
       } else {
           ... code ...
```

The url accessed is dynamic and changes for each day. The problem is in the days when the site goes offline, generates the error "character (0)" when executing the command: >head (Info_ajuste, 20), and the error: "{xml_nodeset (0)}" when executing >head (Info_Ajust_HTML).

This is because it downloads a table and on some days the site does not make that table available.

I needed to create an "if" to skip the days that give this error.

Comment: Take a look at the `tryCatch()` functionality [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093914/use-trycatch-skip-to-next-value-of-loop-upon-error) You can wrap your `read_html` in this and if an error occurs because there is no page for a given date, the loop can skip to the next date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the length of `Info_Ajuste_HTML` and execute remaining code only if some value is captured in it.

```
library(rvest)

while (theDate <= end)
{
  url <- (paste0("http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/produtos-e-servicos/emprestimo-de-ativos/renda-variavel/emprestimos-registrados/renda-variavel-8AE490CA64CD50310164D1EFD6412F1C.htm?data=",format(theDate,"%d/%m/%y"),"&f=0"))
  site <- read_html(url)
  Info_Ajuste_HTML <- html_nodes(site,'table')
  if (length(Info_Ajuste_HTML) > 0) { ### <- Added a check here
      Info_ajuste <- html_text(Info_Ajuste_HTML)
      head(Info_ajuste,20)
      t <- head(Info_Ajuste_HTML)
      ##rest of the code
      ##rest of the code
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!!