# Need help looping these functions over a list of URLs and combining the aggregate data in a table

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

There is an old HTML website with aggregate research data on plant viruses. I am interested in extracting **Susceptible host species** and **Insusceptible host species** data for individual virus species.

[The parent URL containing all individual, paginated URLs for individual species is here.](http://bio-mirror.im.ac.cn/mirrors/pvo/vide/sppindex.htm)

The URLs are paginated from 001 to 911. [An example of one of these URLs, in this case for Abelia latent *tymovirus*, is found here.](http://bio-mirror.im.ac.cn/mirrors/pvo/vide/descr001.htm)

With the kind help of someone on this board, I have managed to generate the code to extract just susceptible/insusceptible data from a single URL. The code:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

#### Preparing for the loop ####

## URL template
url <- 'http://bio-mirror.im.ac.cn/mirrors/pvo/vide/'

## List of all URLs to visit
list_of_pages <- str_c(url, 'descr', c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009", "010","011","012","013","014","015","016","017","018","019","020","021","022","023","024","025","026","027","028","029","030","031","032","033","034","035","036","037","038","039","040","041","042","043","044","045","046","047","048","049","050","051","052","053","054","055","056","057","058","059","060","061","062","063","064","065","066","067","068","069","070","071","072","073","074","075","076","077","078","079","080","081","082","083","084","085","086","087","088","089","090","091","092","093","094","095","096","097","098","099",100:911))
list_of_pages <- str_c(list_of_pages, ".htm")

#### Functions to be executed for each URL

## Obtain URL data for one species (will need to change for loop)
pvo <- read_html("http://bio-mirror.im.ac.cn/mirrors/pvo/vide/descr001.htm")

## Extract URL-specific virus species identifier and cleanup
virus_species <- pvo %>% html_element("center+ h1") %>% html_text()%>% str_replace_all("[\n]" , " ")

## Select only data in node h4, include listitems, and cleanup
all_values <- pvo %>% html_elements("h4, li") %>% html_text() %>% str_replace_all("[\n]" , "")

## Index headings in h4 to isolate susceptibility data
sus_index <- grep('Susceptible host species', all_values, fixed = TRUE)
insus_index <- grep('Insusceptible host species', all_values, fixed = TRUE)
family_sus_index <- grep('Families containing susceptible hosts', all_values, fixed = TRUE)

## Extract susceptible species data
susceptible_species <- all_values[(sus_index+1):(insus_index-1)]

## Extract insusceptible species data
insusceptible_species <- all_values[(insus_index+1):(family_sus_index-1)]
```

Now I would like to apply these functions over my list_of_pages and aggregate the data into one dataframe, ideally looking something like:

[image: Example aggregate data]

Can someone help me accomplish this? I have very little experience with loops and have mostly used dplyr.

EDIT: One very important thing I forgot to add: many of the URLs do not contain susceptibility/insusceptibility data, as the studies simply were not conducted. The loop must be able to continue through these cases and not terminate.

**Examples of these URLs:**

Contains susceptible data but not unsusceptible data:
http://bio-mirror.im.ac.cn/mirrors/pvo/vide/descr565.htm

Contains neither susceptible nor insusceptible data:
http://bio-mirror.im.ac.cn/mirrors/pvo/vide/descr562.htm

Comment: Can you add an example or two of URL's that don't contain the susceptibility/insusceptibility data?

Comment: Of course! I added examples under my edit in the post.

Comment: I also now realize that my indexing won't work for these cases. Why is HTML so hard to scrape from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

#### Preparing for the loop ####

## URL template
url <- 'http://bio-mirror.im.ac.cn/mirrors/pvo/vide/'

## List of all URLs to visit
list_of_pages <- str_c(url, 'descr', c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009", "010","011","012","013","014","015","016","017","018","019","020","021","022","023","024","025","026","027","028","029","030","031","032","033","034","035","036","037","038","039","040","041","042","043","044","045","046","047","048","049","050","051","052","053","054","055","056","057","058","059","060","061","062","063","064","065","066","067","068","069","070","071","072","073","074","075","076","077","078","079","080","081","082","083","084","085","086","087","088","089","090","091","092","093","094","095","096","097","098","099",100:911))
list_of_pages <- str_c(list_of_pages, ".htm")
#list_of_pages <- list_of_pages[641:n_distinct(list_of_pages)]
#### Functions to be executed for each URL

df <- data.frame()

for (pages in list_of_pages) {
  print(pages)
  ## Obtain URL data for one species (will need to change for loop)
  
  ## First catch the Error
  possible_error <- tryCatch(
    pvo <- read_html(pages),
    error = function(e)
      e
  )

  ## If any Error found then just capture it in virus_species column
  ## You will find  "Failed to parse text" where 
  if (inherits(possible_error, 'error')) {
    temp_df <- data.frame(
      pages,
      virus_species = possible_error$message,
      susceptible_species = NA,
      insusceptible_species = NA
    )
    
    df <- rbind(df, temp_df)
    next
  }
  
  ## If no error found reading the html then collect all necessary data
  if (!inherits(possible_error, 'error')) {
    #pvo <- read_html(pages)
    
    ## Extract URL-specific virus species identifier and cleanup
    virus_species <-
      pvo %>% html_element("center+ h1") %>% html_text() %>% str_replace_all("[\n]" , " ")
    
    ## Select only data in node h4, include listitems, and cleanup
    all_values <-
      pvo %>% html_elements("h4, li") %>% html_text() %>% str_replace_all("[\n]" , "")
    
    ## Index headings in h4 to isolate susceptibility data
    sus_index <-
      grep('Susceptible host species', all_values, fixed = TRUE)
    insus_index <-
      grep('Insusceptible host species', all_values, fixed = TRUE)
    family_sus_index <-
      grep('Families containing susceptible hosts', all_values, fixed = TRUE)
    
    ## Extract susceptible species data
    #susceptible_species <- all_values[(sus_index + 1):(insus_index - 1)]
    
    if (length(sus_index) > 0L & length(insus_index) > 0L) {
      susceptible_species <-
        all_values[(sus_index + 1):(insus_index - 1)]
    } else{
      susceptible_species <- NA
    }
    
    ## Extract insusceptible species data
    if (length(insus_index) > 0L & length(family_sus_index) > 0L) {
      insusceptible_species <-
        all_values[(insus_index + 1):(family_sus_index - 1)]
    } else{
      insusceptible_species <- NA
    }
    
    ll <-
      sapply(list(
        virus_species,
        susceptible_species,
        insusceptible_species
      ),
      length)
    
    mll <- max(ll)
    
    temp_df <- data.frame(
      pages = rep(pages, mll),
      virus_species = rep(virus_species, mll),
      susceptible_species = c(susceptible_species, rep(NA, mll - ll[2])),
      insusceptible_species = c(insusceptible_species, rep(NA, mll - ll[3]))
    )
    
    df <- rbind(df, temp_df)
    ## uncomment below line if you need the delay 
    ##Sys.sleep(1) 
    
  }
}

df
```

[For better error handling in r see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093914/use-trycatch-skip-to-next-value-of-loop-upon-error/55937737)

Comment: I appreciate this response so much. Before I try this, do you mind adding a 1000 ms delay in the loop so I don't overload the website or get locked out by the server?

Comment: You can add `Sys.sleep(time)` after `df <- rbind(df, temp_df)` in the loop. Here time is in seconds. i.e. after processing one url it will wait your provided time before loading the next url.

Comment: @DieterKahl I've updated the answer with better error handling and it worked for all url.

Comment: This works incredibly well. Thank you so much.